# How to save disk size in storing pictures in a personal website

Tags: php, html, image, web-services, web

I'm creating a personal website but I'm using a free web hosting it has 2gb disk usage for free...how do i make the pictures save in the host disk less the actual size of the picture if the picture has a big resolution in order to save disk space for future use?

Comment: You can use the PHP image functions to limit the size and set a certain JPG compression level.

Comment: Or just resize it in photoshop if you are the only user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to reduce the size of an image is to compress it or resize it.

If you look at popular websites, their full screen background images are fairly small in size. Most of the time compressing an image will not be noticeable to the average user.

As a rule of thumb, large images on a website should be 200kb or less.